# Checking if user inputs a valid city or country?

Tags: php, html

I can't find a way for the if statement in the checkText function, to check if the city is invalid, Example:

> If you typed "jfeaio" or any other text that doesn't match a city name
>   then it would say "Enter a valid city".

I made a if statement in the function which checks if the input text is "notkoko", if it is then it is going to echo "Enter a valid city" just to test, and it seems to work, but i want it to say that whenever you type something that isn't a city name or a country name.

I've tried a 2 things like:

Using get_headers,
Checking if the file() is false.

The 2 things did work but, then the error would pop up no matter what, like if i typed a valid city name or not.

This is the website

```
http://79.170.40.39/senixmenix.com/PHP/WeatherScraper/index.php
```

Here's the code for both files if you don't want to visit the link

scraper.php(This one is what contains all the PHP)

```
<?php

    $cityTextt = $_GET['city'];
    $result = "";


    $cityTextt = str_replace(' ', '-', $cityTextt);
    $weather = file('http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/'.$cityTextt.'/forecasts/latest');

    $result = $weather[353];

    $headers = "";


    /*if($headers[0] == "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found")
    {

        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" id="fail">You must enter a valid city.</div>';

    }
    else
    {
        echo $result;
    }*/

    function checkText($cityText)
    {
        $headers = @get_headers('http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/'.$cityTextt.'/forecasts/latest');

        if($headers == false)
        {
            throw new Exception('<div class="alert alert-danger" id="fail">You must enter a valid city.</div>');
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    try
    {
        checkText($cityTextt);

        echo $result;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    //print_r($headers);

?>
```

and here's the index.php(This one doesn't contain any PHP)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Jesper's Website</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">

        body{
            font-family: Copperplate Gothic Light, sans-serif;
        }

        .large{
            font-size: 1000%;
        }

        .center{
            text-align: center;
        }

        .bold{
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .marginTop{
            margin-top: 30px;
        }

        .marginRight{
            margin-right: 25px;
        }

        .title{
            margin-top: 60px;
            font-size: 350%;
        }

        .fixedWidth{
            width: 100%;
        }

        #homeContainer{
            width: 100%;
            background: url(images/background1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        #topRow{
            margin-top: 60px;
        }

        #success{
            display: none;
        }

        #faill{
            display: none;
        }

    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container contentContainer" id="homeContainer">

        <div class="row center" id="topRow">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <h1>Weather Scraper</h1>
                <p class="lead">Enter your city below to get a forecast of the Weather</p>

                <form method="post">

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <input type="text" placeholder="Eg. Horsens, New York, Las Vegas" name="city" id="cityText" class="form-control" />

                    </div>

                    <div class="alert alert-success" id="success"></div>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="faill">Enter a city!</div>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="submitBtn" />

                </form>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        var cityInput = "";
        var wHeight = $(window).height();

        $(".contentContainer").css("height", wHeight + "px");

        $("#submitBtn").click(function(event){

            $(".alert").hide();

            cityInput = $("#cityText").val();

            event.preventDefault();

            if(cityInput != "")
            {
                $.get("scraper.php?city=" + cityInput, function(data){

                    if(data == "")
                    {
                        $("#faill").html("Enter a valid city!").slideDown(500);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#success").html(data).slideDown(500);
                    }


                });



            }
            else
            {
                $("#faill").slideDown(500);
            }

        });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: Can I just ask, do you have something like a database table or file or even an array of valid countries which you can use to check if the given country is valid or not?

Comment: No, but i use http://www.weather-forecast.com for the weather and stuff. I made so the users input is in between the locations and forecast http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/San-Diego/forecasts/latest, so if i type in "San Diego" without the quotes then a alert box pops up and tells me the weather, and that information is from that website. So i'm not sure why it wouldn't work if i check if the header is equals to "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found", maybe i'm just thinking weird.

Comment: Adding `@` before the function names suppresses any errors/warnings. Try removing it from `@get_headers`, maybe it will show you any warning or error. Also, have you tried checking what's the value of `$headers` after the request?

Comment: I managed to get it to work, but the warnings/errors is not being hided, even if the @ is there

Comment: @Jesper try to change `$weather = file('http...` to `$weather = @file('http...`. Or you can use command `ini_set('display_errors', '0');` in the tp of your file to hide all warnings.

Comment: @fiction Thanks now i know how to hide warnings/errors :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get_headers will return you an array of headers. In element [0] you will find the return code:

```
http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/San-Diego/forecasts/latest
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/san-diego/forecasts/latest
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently

http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/san diego/forecasts/latest
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

It only returns false if the request fails, e.g. no response from the server.
So you have to change the ***if($headers == false)*** to something different.

Comment: Yeah i changed the if($headers == false) to if($headers[0] == "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"), and that seemed to work

Answer (score 0):

Hm, i can recommend you to use VK Api for this purpose:

https://vk.com/dev/database.getCities ***Returns a list of cities.***
https://vk.com/dev/database.getCountries ***Returns a list of countries.***

In the example search by city was disabled, because its extremely slow (to search every city in world). So if you will sure, that you users will from 1 or two countries, you can specify them in code parameter (getCountries function) and ancomment city search.

Example:

```
<?php

$check = checkCityOrCountry('Cana');
if($check === false)    
    echo 'Not Valid country';
else
{
    echo 'Valid: <pre>';
    print_r($check);
    echo '</pre>';
}

function checkCityOrCountry($name)
{
    $checkCity = $name;
    $checkCity = mb_strtolower($checkCity, "UTF-8");

    $countries = vkapi('database.getCountries', array(
            'need_all' => 1,
            'count' => 1000), null, true);
    $countries = $countries['response'];

    $validString = false;

    $cCnt = count($countries);
    for($i = 0; $i < $cCnt; ++$i)
    {
        $title = mb_strtolower($countries[$i]['title'], "UTF-8");
        if(mb_strpos($title, $checkCity, 0, 'UTF-8') !== false)
        {
            $validString = $countries[$i];
            break;
        }

        /*search by cities too, but extremely long*/
        // $cities = vkapi('database.getCities', array(
        //     'country_id' => $countries[$i]['cid'],
        //     'q' => $checkCity,
        //     'count' => 1000), null, true);
        // $cities = $cities['response'];
        // if(count($cities) > 0)
        // {
        //     $validString = $cities;
        //     break;
        // }
    }

    return $validString;
}
/**
 * @function vkapi          Perform a request to api VK
 * @param  string $method   Name of method
 * @param  array   $params  Post parameters
 * @param  string  $token   Secure token if you need it
 * @param  boolean $array   If = true, will returns an array, in other case - an object
 * @return array            Result
 */
function vkapi($method, $params = array(), $token=null, $array=false) {
    try
    {
        $rid = 0;
        if(isset($token))
            $params["access_token"] = $token;

        $params['lang'] = 'en';
        $paramstr = http_build_query($params);
        $url = "https://api.vk.com/method/" . $method . "?" . $paramstr;

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

        if($array == true)
        {
            $result = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
        }

        return $result;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        throw new Exception('VK API: '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he don't need real city names but just the cities that are valid on the weather website of which he "steals" the content.

Comment: Yes, i understand. But maybe it will helps him.

Comment: @hellcode Yeah, this was only for practice purposes tho ^^

fiction: Thanks, that will probably help me in the future when i need it :-)

Answer (score 0):

On the weather-forecast i've found a typeahead search field. this check with specific url if city exits or not.
it's not a great soultion but it works.

```
$city = 'test';

$data =  file_get_contents('http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/ac_location_name?query='.$city);

if (strlen($data) > 6) {
    echo ucfirst($city)." is valid!";
} else {
    echo ucfirst($city)." is not valid!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('color_id').style.height="0.0001px";document.getElementById("color_id").style.backgroundColor = "red";
function jsonpRequest(url, data)
{
    let params = "";
    for (let key in data)
    {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            if (params.length == 0)
            {
                params += "?";
            }
            else
            {
                params += "&";
            }
            let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(key);
            let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
            params += encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue;
         }
    }
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url + params;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function getGMT()
{

let lat_str=document.getElementById("lat_id").value;
if (document.getElementById("lat_id").value==""){
  document.getElementById("color_id").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

if (document.getElementById("lat_id").value!=""){
  let url = "https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json";
  let data = {
    callback:"displayGMT",
    q:lat_str,
    key:"d659864579124f76ac1bb0ccdbcccbcc"
  }
  jsonpRequest(url, data)
 }
 }

function displayGMT(data)
{
if (data.results==""){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Invalid";
document.getElementById("color_id").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

if ((Number(data.results[0].annotations.timezone.offset_string))>0 ||(Number(data.results[0].annotations.timezone.offset_string))<0){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("color_id").style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
}

getGMT()
setInterval(getGMT, 300)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="lat_id" placeholder="Enter a place"><br>
 <input type="text"  id="color_id">
<font size="3" color="red" ><p id="demo"></p></font>
```

Comment: If city is valid, line will turn green whereas if a city is invalid, line will turn red and an alert message invalid will pop up. Hope this helps